# How can I do arithmetic on CUDA's __half type in host side code?

Tags: c++, cuda, half-precision-float

I have a kernel I'm running on an NVIDIA GPU, which uses the FP16 type __half, provided by `cuda_fp16.hpp`. To check something about its behavior, I also want to manipulate such `__half` values on the CPU. However, when I try to apply arithmetic operations to them in host-side code, I get an error, since they're defined like so:

```
__device__ __forceinline__ __half operator+(const __half &lh, const __half &rh) { return __hadd(lh, rh); }
__device__ __forceinline__ __half operator-(const __half &lh, const __half &rh) { return __hsub(lh, rh); }
__device__ __forceinline__ __half operator*(const __half &lh, const __half &rh) { return __hmul(lh, rh); }
__device__ __forceinline__ __half operator/(const __half &lh, const __half &rh) { return __hdiv(lh, rh); }
```

how can I, therefore, use these values on the host (Other than by upcasting and downcasting every time, I mean)?

Note: Using CUDA 11.2.

Comment: switch to a newer version of CUDA. I have no issues using these operators in host code in CUDA 12.2, and the definitions are not as you have shown here.   A quick binary search in godbolt suggests to me that CUDA 12.2 is the first version that has these host/device definitions.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: It had not occurred to me this might be version-dependent. I may have some CUDA version constraints, but - this is good advice, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RobertCrovella mentions in a comment - newer versions of CUDA (e.g. 12.2) also offer a host-side versions of these functions.

Alternatively, C++23 offers a proper 16-bit floating-point type, `std::float16_t`, which you can apply arithmetic operations to; and `std::bfloat16_t` is also available. See:

[Fixed width floating-point types (since C++23)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/floating-point)

on [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com).

For older C++ standard versions, you can use the available compiler-specific half-precision floating point types and builtins, such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half-Precision.html)'s, to perform the computation.